# R version 4.1.0

Tags: r

I currently updated my R to version 4.1.0 and I noticed that there are some changes in the functions/commands.
I am trying to read some files using a loop. Before, I used to use the following command:
`for (i in levels(fileslist$Names)){print(paste(i))}`.
However, I noticed that in version 4.1.0 this command does not work. Does anyone know what command I should use instead in the newer version?

Comment: Character values are no longer automatically converted to factors when you import data. Try `for (i in unique(fileslist$Names)) {print(i)}`. Using `unique()` will work with characters since characters do not have `levels()`